# Get a file location in Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I am writing an Eclipse plugin where I want to read a file within the project and do something on it.
For example the file is located under : Project testplugin and path : com/flow/FlowMain.java
I want to programmatically read this file and add some code in it.
What I trying is :

> String base = Platform.getBundle(config.getPluginId()).getEntry("/").toString();
>   String relativeUri = "com/flow/FlowMain.java";
>   File f = new File(base+relativeUri);

This obviously fails because the value of "base+relativeUri" returns :
entry://1079.fwk5184781/com/flow/FlowMain.java

So how do I go about getting the complete file path from within the plugin ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve a file from within a folder in the workspace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148821/retrieve-a-file-from-within-a-folder-in-the-workspace)

Comment: Yes, you need the second method of traversing from the workspace root, not from the bundle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'entry' is a protocol defined by equinox, so you can get the real path using org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.toFileURL(URL).

Comment: From the post suggested by Fabian, I am trying to get the root workspace and locating the actual file. I get an NPE doing this. The root workspace itself seems to be coming as null. I get NPE when I try     System.out.println(resourceInRuntimeWorkspace.getName()); One thing to clarify that I am running this code "as an eclipse application"

Comment: Another problem I face is that the file resides in the project folder so the path should be "projectname"+/com/flow/FlowMain.java. Now how do I get the name of the current project and append it to the path ? Is there a way to get it from IWorkspaceRoot ?

Comment: one thing you must pay attention, the bundle instance obtained via Platform.getBundle(config.getPluginId()) is the bundle in your running target platform.
For example, it's your plug-in project in your workspace. You can get the absolute path of the project folder when executing the code in eclipse. However it's a jar file in the target platform, say as the bundle 'org.eclipse.core.runtime'. When you trying to get its location, the jar will be extracted to osgi data folder.

Comment: try below code snippet, it helps you understand,

URL base = Platform.getBundle("org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core").getEntry("OSGI-INF/eventBus.xml");
System.out.println(base);
System.out.println(FileLocator.toFileURL(base));

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to get the plugin path :

```
String workSpaceRootpath=this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()+Relativepath of a file;
```